# how to merge the hours minutes and seconds from a multiline string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, sum

i am getting a `multiline` string in `ruby`. lets say

```
s = "00:01:07,11-234-090
     00:05:01,22-080-080
     00:05:00,11-234-090"
```

this string is separated by new line characters (\n). i want a method which sums up the duration (left side part of comma in every new line ex (00:01:07) based on the string(right side part after the comma in every line) means the first line and last line contains the same string after the comma (11-234-090). and in the second line the string after the comma is (22-080-080) as there is no same string in the entire string i want to keep this line as same.

```
input = "00:01:07,11-234-090
         00:05:01,22-080-080
         00:05:00,11-234-090"

output : "00:06:07,11-234-090
          00:05:01,22-080-080"
```

here the `00` represent hour , `06` represents minutes and `07` represents seconds.

i want a method which returns the desired string by taking the input string

```
def returs_sumation_string(input_string)
  return desired_string
end
```

i tried this:

```
   s = "00:01:07,400-234-090
   00:05:01,701-080-080
   00:05:00,400-234-090" 

   splited = s.split("\n")
   splited.map!{|s| s.strip}
```

this much i know. do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: What have you tried? You should show some effort and not just ask strangers to do your work.

Comment: i tried this.    s = "00:01:07,400-234-090
   00:05:01,701-080-080
   00:05:00,400-234-090" 
  
  splited = s.split("\n") ;
  splited!.map{|s| s.strip};  here iam getting an array of array here i am not sure how to merge the duration based on numbers.

Comment: you can either go further and split the time and merge each piece or you convert it to a [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) object and add them together then convert it back to your string representation

Comment: Is this some sort of homework or test? Just wondering because I found almost the same code here: https://github.com/yukas/codility-exercises/blob/master/8%20(Phone).rb

Comment: and here http://pastie.org/pastes/10447727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def aggregate(str)
  str.strip.split(/\n\s*/).group_by { |s| s[-10..-1] }.map do |k,a|
    secs = a.reduce(0) do |t,s|
      h,m,s = s.split(":").map(&:to_i)
      t + 3600*h + 60*m + s
    end
    h,secs = secs.divmod(3600)
    m,secs = secs.divmod(60) 
    "%0#{h>99 ? 3:2 }d:%02d:%02d,%s" % [h,m,secs,k]
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "00:01:07,11-234-090
       00:05:01,22-080-080
       00:05:00,11-234-090"

aggregate(str)
  #=> ["00:06:07,11-234-090", "00:05:01,22-080-080"]
```

**Explanation**

See the docs for methods [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) and [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod).

For `str` given in the example, the main steps are as follows.

```
b = str.strip
  #=> "00:01:07,11-234-090\n         00:05:01,22-080-080\n         00:05:00,11-234-090" 
c = b.split(/\n\s*/)
  #=> ["00:01:07,11-234-090", "00:05:01,22-080-080", "00:05:00,11-234-090"]
d = c.group_by { |s| s[-10..-1] }
  #=> {"11-234-090"=>["00:01:07,11-234-090", "00:05:00,11-234-090"],
  #    "22-080-080"=>["00:05:01,22-080-080"]}
d.map do |k,a|
  secs = a.reduce(0) do |t,s|
    h,m,s = s.split(":").map(&:to_i)
    t + 3600*h + 60*m + s
  end
  h,secs = secs.divmod(3600)
  m,secs = secs.divmod(60) 
  "%0#{h>99 ? 3:2 }d:%02d:%02d,%s" % [h,m,secs,k]
end
  #=> ["00:06:07,11-234-090", "00:05:01,22-080-080"]
```

Now let's break down the last step. `map` passes the first element of `c` (an array containing a key-value pair) to the block, to which the block variables are assigned, using *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*):

```
k, a = d.first
  #=> ["11-234-090", ["00:01:07,11-234-090", "00:05:00,11-234-090"]] 
k #=> "11-234-090" 
a #=> ["00:01:07,11-234-090", "00:05:00,11-234-090"]
```

and the block calculation is performed. First we calculate the total number of seconds for the two elements of `a`. I've added some `puts` statements to show the calculations.

```
secs = a.reduce(0) do |t,s|
  puts "  t=#{t}, s=#{s}"
  puts "    h,m,s = #{s.split(":")}"
  h,m,s = s.split(":").map(&:to_i)
  puts "    h=#{h}, m=#{m}, s=#{s}"
  puts "    t + 3600*h + 60*m + s=#{t + 3600*h + 60*m + s}"
  t + 3600*h + 60*m + s
end
# t=0, s=00:01:07,11-234-090
#   h,m,s = ["00", "01", "07,11-234-090"]
#   h=0, m=1, s=7
#   t + 3600*h + 60*m + s=67
# t=67, s=00:05:00,11-234-090
#   h,m,s = ["00", "05", "00,11-234-090"]
#   h=0, m=5, s=0
#   t + 3600*h + 60*m + s=367
#=> 367
```

Continuing,

```
  h,secs = secs.divmod(3600)
    #=> [0, 367] 
  h
    #=> 0 
  secs
    #=> 367 
  m,secs = secs.divmod(60) 
    #=> [6, 7] 
  m
    #=> 6 
  secs
    #=> 7 
  "%0#{h>99 ? 3:2 }d:%02d:%02d,%s" % [h,m,secs,k]
    #=> "00:06:07,11-234-090"
```

The final statement, the formatting of the string that is returned, uses format codes listed in the doc for [Kernel::format](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-format). `"%02d"` means to format an integer `2` characters wide with zeroes used for any left padding required (e.g., `"%02d" % [9] #=> "09"`). `"%0#{h>99 ? 3:2 }"` means that the field width for hours should be `3` if there are more than `99` hours, else the width is `2`.

Calculations for the second element of `c` are similar.

The `group_by` expression, `group_by { |s| s[-10..-1] }` means group the strings (produced by `split`) by the last `10` characters of the string. Alternatively, one could replace the first line with the following.

```
str.strip.split(/\n\s*/).group_by { |s| s.split(",").last }
```

Comment: will this method works for dynamic input , which contains any n number of lines of string?

Comment: John, yes to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me, what is happening at this line (c = b.group_by { |s| s[9..-1] })